# Mentioning about a exhibition on CV

Tags: resume, conferences

Recently, I participated as an exhibitor at an Internet-of-Things (IoT) Tech Expo in Amsterdam. It was a great experience and I think this is something I should mention on my CV.

**Is this a good practice or is totally useless?**

**Is this something people usually do?**

I have to say that this experience can not help me do my daily work as an Embedded Developer, but it adds value as a professional generally.

Comment: Depends on how thin your CV is. If you don't have much experience, (almost) anything helps. If you've been working for 30 years, it's probably not much use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr** It is a good idea to mention it in CV

This for sure is something to be shared on your CV. Employers given two identical CVs will look for things like this to decide which of potential employees will be a better match.

It will show that you are passionate about what you do, proactive and engaged with the community. And all of those are traits of a desired employee. It let's the employer get to know you a little better before he actually hires you.

Regarding if it's something people usually do. I cannot speak for everyone but I've seen people put charity work they've done in their CVs even if it wasn't strictly connected to their profession and I don't think it ever hurt them.

Comment: "t will show that you are passionate about what you do, proactive and engaged with the community" OR it shows he was ordered to participate by his then job? Or tried to make some money? While I appreciate HR Spin dumptalk, trying to sell something is not "participating in the community", unless you work in HR and try to get some more multi level marketing people (you know, because of community).